# How to detect the usage rights (DRM) of a file

Tags: .net, encryption, encoding, drm, wma

Suppose you have a .wma / .wmv file and you want to detect:

1. is it DRM protected ?
2. (then hopefully) details of the DRM protection (like when does the license expire etc.)?

Is there a C# / C++ api for it? It seems that Windows Media Player can do it - if you click properties on that file... but Explorer does not show this info.

Note: I do not belive this is a trivial question, I have tried taglib and searched the web for a solution for about 2 hours now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Here](http://www.windowskb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/windows-media-drm/964/can-i-detect-the-files-already-DRM). More info on the Format SDK [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb190326.aspx)

> In c# using the Format SDK:

```
[DllImport("WMVCore.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]

private static extern int WMIsContentProtected(string pwszFileName, out bool 
pfIsProtected);
```

Comment: This only works for XP :( Well, I did manage to make it work on Win 7, but it does fail on Win 2003.l

Answer (score 8):

One method of detecting DRM files under a folder using Powershell is: -

```
$wmplayer = New-Object -ComObject "WMPlayer.OCX"
ls -recurse | ? { $_.Name -like "*.wma" -and [bool]::Parse($wmplayer.newMedia($_.FullName).getItemInfo("Is_Protected")) }
```

Comment: This answer turned out to be just what I needed. I tested it a little to make sure it could be piped to `rm`, and then did that to remove all the DRM-cruft in my music folder: `ls -recurse | ? { $_.Name -like "*.wma" -and [bool]::Parse($wmplayer.newMedia($_.FullName).getItemInfo("Is_Protected")) } | rm`

Comment: Wow, this is an very useful response.  It worked like a charm on all my wma files that still have DRM on them.